# improving readiblity and be slightly less explicit using Linq

Tags: linq, c#-3.0

All,

I've got the following code, and looking into ways to improve its readibility (and remove the null check) by using Linq.

```
var activePlan = CurrentPlans.First();
var activeObjectives = activePlan != null ? activePlan.Objectives : null;
```

The closest I get is the following:

```
var activeObjectives = CurrentPlans.Take(1).Select(x => x.Objectives);
```

which gives me a collection of x.Objectives instead of Objectives.
Any ideas?

Comment: In your original code, the null check is useless, because `CurrentPlans.First()` will not return null if there is no items in the collection: it will throw an exception. You need to use `FirstOrDefault` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oh got it:

```
var activeObjectives = CurrentPlans.Take(1).SelectMany(x => x.Objectives)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx

Comment: Is someone here trying to get `Self-Learner` badge? :D

Answer (score 4):

I'd write if like this:

```
var activeObjectives = CurrentPlans.Select(x => x.Objectives).FirstOrDefault();
```

This way, it's easier to work out the intention by the use of methods.  Take the first set of objectives, otherwise the default (null assuming Objectives refers to a reference type).  Using `SelectMany()` for this case isn't the best choice IMO.